# ASP.NET application can not hit the SOAP web server while SOAPUI can

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, wcf, soap

I have an local ASP.NET application consuming SOAP web service hosted on a server. I am able to add reference of the service successfully, but when I am trying to execute the application, it throws an endpoint not found exception. The specific error message is: "Could not connect to https://xxxxxxxx. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it". However, it returns correct data When I am trying it with SOAPUI. Does anyone know why this is happening in visual studio? I have double checked the service url in the asp.net web.config file is correct.

Comment: First of all, did you use "Add Service Reference" to create the client classes?

Comment: Yes, I did. The application builds successfully. The exception happens in page_loading when it trying to send the first request to the server

Comment: That message usually means either that the service is not running, or that it's not possible to contact the service due to firewall rules, anti-virus or such.

Comment: I thought that too, but SOAPUI can hit the server. So I am sure the service is running fine and no firewall blocks.

Comment: Firewalls can be configured to only allow certain applications to pass data.

Comment: Is the web service hosted in .net?

Comment: No, it is a java web service, hosted in websphere.